# JSF2.0 identify values changed in the entire form

Tags: user-interface, jsf-2

I am working on JSF2.0 project where a screen has got 60 fields with prepopulated values.
User can edit any number of fields in the screen and I have to display the user edited fields with old and new values in the next screen when he clicks on 'Save' button.

What would be the best way to do  that .
Screen should be this way

```
FieldName  Old Value          New Value
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything? If yes then post that code.

Comment: @Satyam Koyani  I tried using BeanUtils to iterate through all fields and compare the old  value from DB against new values the user has entered

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that your prepopulated values have pulled from database in some object, called someObject which is a field of SomeBean, and displayed like

`<h:inputText value="#{someBean.someObject.someValue}">`.

After someObject has been populated from database, you can make another (copy) object: oldSomeObject, to which you copy the field values of the someObject. After submitting form with 60 values, on new page, you can call method from SomeBean:

```
public ArrayList<EditedField> getEditedFields(){
    ArrayList<EditedField> editedFields = new ArrayList<EditedField>();
    for(int i=0; i<oldSomeObject.getFieldValues().size(); i++){
        if(!someObject.getFieldValues().contains(oldSomeObject.getFieldValues().get(i))){
           editedFields.add(new EditedField(oldSomeObject.getFieldNames.get(i), oldSomeObject.getFieldValues().get(i), someObject.getFieldValues().get(i)));
        }
    }
    return editedFields;
}
```

Here:

getFieldValues() is method in class SomeObject, which returns ArrayList of (String) values of all fields,

getFieldNames() is method in class SomeObject, which returns ArrayList of names of all fields (same order),

EditedField is a class which describe edited field:

```
public class EditedField(){

    private String fieldName;
    private String oldValue;
    private String newValue;

    public EditedField(String fieldName, String oldValue, String newValue){
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.oldValue = oldValue;
        this.newValue = newValue;
    }

    public void setFieldName(String fieldName){
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public String getFieldName(){
        return fieldName;
    }

    public void setOldValue(String oldValue){
        this.oldValue= oldValue;
    }

    public String getOldValue(){
        return oldValue;
    }

    public void setNewValue(String newValue){
        this.newValue= newValue;
    }

    public String getNewValue(){
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

Page that displays edited fields in table, should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:body>
    <h:dataTable value="#{someBean.editedFields}" var="field">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Field Name"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{field.fieldName}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Old Value"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{field.oldValue}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="New Value"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{field.newValue}"></h:outputText>
        </h:column>

</h:body>
</html>
```

I hope it will help.